# How to catch an event when the control is covered by another control?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have small problem here, at the application runtime, I move a bit a Control over my Panel (with own Paint method). The problem is, how to catch that event, to make my Panel repaint?

EDIT:

but, I can't find the event name which will be raised when a Control covers my Panel, that's all about

I thought it's Panel.Leave but I was wrong

Comment: Please add some more details. The paint event should normally cover this w/o any extra effort.

Answer (score 0):

You have to catch the event of the control, and then write code to repaint the panel (if I am understanding your question correctly).

Answer (score 0):

You can also call the Panel's Invalidate() method to cause it to redraw at the end of your painting routine.